How to force 2 coroutines never run simultaneously
In this code:
private suspend fun doSthSingleThreaded(){
    coroutineScope {
        //Coroutine 1
        launch {
            //do sth that will suspend
        }
        //Coroutine 2
        launch {
            //Do sth else that will suspend too
        }
    }
}

Is there a way that I can make these 2 Coroutines behave like they are sharing the underlying thread? this is how I want it to work ( I want to adjust the code in a way that they both use threadA):

Coroutine 1 runs on threadA ( Coroutine 2 is suspended )
Coroutine 1 gets suspended, and Coroutine 2 runs on threadA
Coroutine 2 finished it's job, and Coroutine 1 continues on threadA until it is done, and then the function returns.

EDIT:
This is Y I want to do this:
I have a SharedFlow that is somehow a single source of truth for all the data I receive from a serial port.
val hotFlow = SharedFlow<String> //buffer = ALot, replay = 0

Any time I write anything to that port I read it's answer from here. like this:
port.writeSth()
val answer = hotFlow.first {it == "OK" || it == "ERROR"}
if (answer == "OK") return
//process error

The problem with the code above (with replay = 0) is that HotFlow sometimes returns a response and then returns sth else so quickly that I am not able catch my answer!
Why replay = 0? All the different commands that I write to this port have the answer "OK" or "ERROR", and the port does not return anything that says what command this answer belongs to. So if replay != 0:
port.writeSth()
val portCache = hotFlow.replay
//Now how do I know if the last item is my answer or I should still wait?

so I thought maybe I can:
launch {
    val answer = hotFlow.first{it == "OK" || it == "ERROR" }
    //process answer
}
launch {
    port.writeSth()
}

order of execution:

Collect everything from port and suspend
Write something
First suspended coroutine definitely catches the answer


While newSingleThreadContext would be correct, this might be an X/Y problem. Even just preventing parallelism with limitedParallelism might be overkill. What is your ultimate motive for wanting to run this on the same thread? If you want to prevent concurrent access to a shared resource, you could also consider a coroutine Mutex just around the parts that need protection.

Definitely seems like an XY problem. You can do this, but the fact that you want to is a code smell.

Thanks. I tried to add the Y problem too. I should say I had mentioned one thread because I though that was the only way I could have that particular order of execution.

Based on your description, I think you should be using a Channel instead of a SharedFlow.

You can get a single thread bound coroutine dispatcher with newSingleThreadContext, but please be wary:

A dedicated thread is a very expensive resource. In a real application it must be either released, when no longer needed, using the close function, or stored in a top-level variable and reused throughout the application.

If instead you only need to limit parallelism you can use limitedParallelism instead: Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(1). This will not guarantee that the coroutines will always use the same thread, only that at most one coroutine is executed at the same time.
private suspend fun doSthSingleThreaded() {
    val confined = newSingleThreadContext("My Thread")
//    or
//    val confined = Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(1)
    withContext(confined) {
        //Coroutine 1
        launch {
            //do sth that will suspend
        }
        //Coroutine 2
        launch {
            //Do sth else that will suspend too
        }        
    }
}


Limited parallelism was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks A LOT.

I have updated my answer with a better way to set context for multiple coroutines at once - start them in a single threaded context created with withContext. @khebrati
